# Theming link fields, getting URL value

Tags: theming, 8, entities, navigation

From a field template level, how can I get the link field URL value so I can theme this thing? Here is my overridden field template for this field:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {%
      set classes = [
        'btn',
        (loop.index0 == 0) ? 'btn--primary' : 'btn--inverted'
      ]
    %}

    <a href="{{ item.content['#uri'] }}" class="{{ classes|join(' ') }}">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

It only holds two possible values.

I have tried every possible way to access the field value, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's bad practice to create the anchor tag like above.

Comment: You should create a link render array in preprocess and revert it instead.

Comment: Revert? You mean render?

Comment: Yes, I meant render (autocorrect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the theming of the link field from a field twig level, it might be a better approach to keep the existing link render element, which is in `item.content` and add the bootstrap classes to it:

**field--link.html.twig**

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a field.
 *
 * Add bootstrap button style to a link field
 */
#}
{% for item in items %}
  {%
    set link_classes = [
      'btn',
      (loop.index0 == 0) ? 'btn--primary' : 'btn--inverted'
    ]
  %}
  {% set content = item.content %}
  {% set content = content|merge({ '#attributes': { class: link_classes } }) %}
  {{ content }}
{% endfor %}
```

You have to get `item.content` on the top level of the array, so that you can merge `#attibutes`. That is why you need `{% set content = item.content %}`.

Comment: Interesting - where in the docs did you see this

Comment: That's my code.

Comment: Ok, so you can merge them into the render array at this point. That works. I assume you can add other attributes here if you wanted to as well, other than class?

Comment: Yes, that's the same as in preprocess. If the variable contains a render array you can change it. The problem is, that twig has not very much tools to manipulate arrays, so for more complex things you better use php.

Answer (score 5):

Ok... found my answer.

There are two ways you could do this. One way, is in the themename.theme file:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#bundle'] == 'motivation_card' && $variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_link') {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $index => $item) {
      $variables['items'][$index]['content']['url'] = $item['content']['#url']->toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Another (preferable) way that I used is to use the [render_var](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Template!TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3ArenderVar/8.2.x) twig function.

```
{{ render_var(item.content['#url']) }}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the render_var function call. Try `{{ item.content['#url'] }}`

Comment: That didn't do anything without the render_var.